# Why can't I use a function to do collision check in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop, requestanimationframe

I have a simple collision detection working that lets you jump off of blocks, and yet if I call a function that has the same code block in it. It will break.

call without the function:

```
    for(let i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++){
        if(blockCollision(sprite, blocks[i])){
            sprite.vy = 0;
            // sprite.vy += gravity;

            if(blockCollisionLeft(sprite, blocks[i])){
                sprite.vx = 0;
                sprite.x = blocks[i].x - sprite.w - offset;
            }
            if(blockCollisionRight(sprite, blocks[i])){
                sprite.vx = 0;
                sprite.x = blocks[i].x + blocks[i].w + offset;
            }

            if(blockCollisionTop(sprite, blocks[i])){
                sprite.y = blocks[i].y - sprite.h - offset;
                sprite.canJump = true;
            }else{
                // sprite.vy = 0;
                sprite.y = blocks[i].y + blocks[i].h + offset;
                sprite.vy += gravity;
            }
        }
    }
```

and the call with the function:

```
    for(let i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++){
         if(blockCollision(sprite, blocks[i])){
             checkCollisions(sprite, blocks[i]);
             break;
         }
    }
```

I'm not sure what to do at this point, the sprite block keeps jumping out of control, can't quite understand why a function call would do this.

```js
const PI = Math.PI;
const offset = 1;
const gravity = .33;

function inCanvas(obj){
    if(obj.x - offset < 0 && obj.x + obj.w + offset > w
        && obj.y - offset < 0 && obj.y + obj.h + offset > h){
            return true;
        }
    return false;
}

function groundCollision(obj){
    if(obj.y + obj.h + offset == h){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

function blockCollision(obj, block){
    if(obj.x - offset < block.x + block.w && obj.x + obj.w + offset > block.x
        && obj.y - offset < block.y + block.h && obj.y + obj.h + offset > block.y){
            return true;
        }
    return false;
}

function blockCollisionTop(obj, block){    
    if(obj.y + obj.h + offset > block.y && obj.y + obj.h + offset < block.y + block.h){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

function blockCollisionLeft(obj, block){
    if(obj.x + obj.w + offset > block.x && obj.x + obj.w < block.x){
            return true;
        }
    return false;
}

function blockCollisionRight(obj, block){
    if(obj.x - offset < block.x + block.w && obj.x > block.x + block.w){
            return true;
        }
    return false;
}

function Sprite(_x, _y, _w, _h){
    this.x = _x;
    this.y = _y;
    this.w = _w;
    this.h = _h;

    this.vx = 0;
    this.vy = 0;
    this.jv = -11;

    this.canJump = false;

    // this.maxv = 3;
};

Sprite.prototype.draw = function(){
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
};

Sprite.prototype.update = function(){
    this.x += this.vx;
    this.y += this.vy;
    this.vy += gravity;
    // this.yv -= gravity;
    // this.xv -= gravity;
    // this.xv += gravity;

    if(this.y + this.h + offset > h){
        this.y = h - this.h - offset;
    }
    if(this.y - offset < 0){
        this.y = offset;
    }
    if(this.x - offset < 0){
        this.x = offset;
    }
    if(this.x + this.w + offset > w){
        this.x = w - this.w - offset;
    }
};

Sprite.prototype.jump = function(){
    this.vy = this.jv;
};
function Block(_x, _y, _w, _h){
    this.x = _x;
    this.y = _y;
    this.w = _w;
    this.h = _h;

    this.steppedOn = false;
};

Block.prototype.draw = function(){
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
};
const canvas = document.getElementById("game");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const w = canvas.width = 600;
const h = canvas.height = 600;

var right = false,
    left = false,
    up = false;

var sprite = new Sprite(100, 200, 20, 40);
var box1 = new Block(w - 300, h - 80, 300, 10);
var blocks = [];

for(let i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
    blocks.push(new Block(Math.round(Math.random() * w), Math.round(Math.random() * h), w/4 + Math.round(Math.random() * (w)), 15));
}

//console.log(blocks);

(function update(){
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);

    sprite.draw();
    for(let i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++){
        blocks[i].draw();
    }
    box1.draw();
    sprite.update();

    // pOne.xv = left ? -2 : right ? 2 : 0;
    if(left && right){
        sprite.vx = 0;
    }
    else if(left){
        sprite.vx = -2;
    }
    else if(right){
        sprite.vx = 2;
    }
    else{
        sprite.vx = 0;
    }

    if(up && sprite.canJump){
        sprite.jump();
        sprite.canJump = false;
    }

    if(groundCollision(sprite)){
        sprite.canJump = true;
    }

    checkCollisions(sprite, box1);

    for(let i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++){
        if(blockCollision(sprite, blocks[i])){
            checkCollisions(sprite, blocks[i]);
             break;
         }
    }
    
    // if(blockCollision(sprite, box1)){
    //     // checkCollisions(sprite, box1);
    //     sprite.vy = 0;
    //     // sprite.vy += gravity;

    //     if(blockCollisionLeft(sprite, box1)){
    //         sprite.vx = 0;
    //         sprite.x = box1.x - sprite.w - offset;
    //     }
    //     if(blockCollisionRight(sprite, box1)){
    //         sprite.vx = 0;
    //         sprite.x = box1.x + box1.w + offset;
    //     }

    //     if(box1.steppedOn = blockCollisionTop(sprite, box1)){
    //         sprite.y = box1.y - sprite.h - offset;
    //         sprite.canJump = true;
    //     }else{
    //         // sprite.vy = 0;
    //         sprite.y = box1.y + box1.h + offset;
    //         sprite.vy += gravity;
    //     }
    // }

    window.addEventListener("keydown", (e)=>{
        // console.log(e.key);
        if(e.key == "a" || e.key == "ArrowLeft"){
            left = true;
        }
        if(e.key == "d" || e.key == "ArrowRight"){
            right = true;
        }
        if(e.key == " " || e.key == "ArrowUp"){
            up = true;
        }
    });

    window.addEventListener("keyup", (e)=>{
        if(e.key == "a" || e.key == "ArrowLeft"){
            left = false;
        }
        if(e.key == "d" || e.key == "ArrowRight"){
            right = false;
        }
        if(e.key == " " || e.key == "ArrowUp"){
            up = false;
        }
    });

    window.requestAnimationFrame(update);
}());

function checkCollisions(obj, block){
    if(blockCollision(obj, block)){
        obj.vy = 0;
        // obj.vy += gravity;

        if(blockCollisionLeft(obj, block)){
            obj.vx = 0;
            obj.x = block.x - obj.w - offset;
        }
        if(blockCollisionRight(obj, block)){
            obj.vx = 0;
            obj.x = block.x + block.w + offset;
        }

        if(block.steppedOn = blockCollisionTop(obj, block)){
            obj.y = obj.y - obj.h - offset;
            obj.canJump = true;
        }else{
            // obj.vy = 0;
            obj.y = block.y + block.h + offset;
            obj.vy += gravity;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Block Jump</title>
    <style>
        *{margin:0; padding: 0;}
            #game{
                display:inherit;
                margin:30px auto;
                border:thin solid black;
            }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="game"></canvas>
    <script src="JS/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: `box1.steppedOn = blockCollisionTop(sprite, blocks[i])` assigns `box1.steppedOn` to `blockCollisionTop(sprite, blocks[i])`. Did you mean to _compare_ the two?

Comment: No, i was assigning the object property, it should be blocks[i].steppedOn but no matter, it's not used anyways

Comment: Then why is this assignment in an `if` condition?

Comment: i used one less line of code i guess...

Comment: A good style guide for that situation, _if_ you are using assignments in conditions, is to surround them with parentheses; this signifies to most people (and style checkers) that you actually intended the assignment. (Still better to use one more line in most cases.) Another thing I notice is that you attach new event handlers in each animation frame; this is likely not what you want. I can't see anything about the loop issue though.

Comment: thanks for your input, the code works fine without the function call for the collision check (checkCollisions(obj, block)). If you run it in the snippet you'll see the block jumping up and down continuously. But when I don't use the function, it does not. I was just wondering what would be causing the issue, as it can't be a exceeded callback issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first two code snippets are not equivalent, you seem to have added a break statement in your example with a function. This will have the effect of terminating the for loop prematurely when `blockCollision(sprite, blocks[i])` is true, which might be why you are seeing a difference between the two.

edit:
You also seem to have changed the third if-block slightly in your function. In your first code snippet that if-block is defined as:

```
if(blockCollisionTop(sprite, blocks[i])){
    sprite.y = blocks[i].y - sprite.h - offset;
    sprite.canJump = true;
}
```

but in your function is defined as:

```
if(block.steppedOn = blockCollisionTop(obj, block)){
    obj.y = obj.y - obj.h - offset;
    obj.canJump = true;
}
```

which is not equivalent because you have replaced `blocks[i]` with `obj`, but it should be `block`.

Comment: Unfortunately, it did nothing after removing it. I was hoping to break out of the loop once it detects a collision between the block and sprite.

Comment: OK, it could be due to the other differences in my updated answer.

Comment: switched the obj to block and it fixed it. thank you.